# Talend : Truncate Table and insert data from a view

Tags: oracle, talend, esb, truncate

i'm working on a job with Tos for ESB 7.1.1. I'm trying to connect to a DB (ORACLE), recover my ID_MAX and save it, TRUNCATE my table and insert data from a view and for each line increment my ID.

**What I have done :**

- Connect to my DB (add it to my meta) : OK
- Save my ID_MAX (save in a context) : OK

**What is my problem :**

I have an error when I want to TRUNCATE my table :

Exception in component tDBOutput_1 (ODS_TEMPF_PROGRAMMES_TRUNCATE)
java.lang.RuntimeException: For delete, the schema must have a key

I created a special Job just for truncate my table this is my designer :

[image]

and my tDBOutput :

[image]fAM.png

I Don't know if there is any other way to do a TRUNCATE in Talend, so i'm waiting for your help.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's was just a basic SQL mistake… I wrote `server_myTable` and it's was `server.myTable`…

I close the subject.